# Datetime retrieved from db is 7 hours off?

Tags: datetime

I am having trouble displaying the correct date, well actually its only the time.

In the db the date is stored in this form: `2012-09-28 23:30:00`

That is the value for a date of an event.

When I retrieve it using this script:

```
$ttdate = $obj->field_date_test_value;
$nttdate = strtotime($ttdate);
$okdate = format_date($nttdate, $type = 'medium');
print $okdate;
```

...it works fine but the time is off by 7 hours.
So instead of showing `Fri, 9/28/2012 - 4:30pm` it shows `Fri, 9/28/2012 - 11:30pm`.

Note that on the event's page, drupal retrieves the correct time...

I did some research and I figured it has to do with the timezone? But I have the timezone set to Los Angeles so I am not quite sure what is going on. Maybe its my script?

Comment: [Set timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in beginning of the script for your [zone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) But am not sure why you posted this in Drupal SE instead of Stackoverflow

Comment: Did you check the time on the server hosting the site ??

Comment: @kantu shouldn't drupal automatically set the timezone?

Comment: @june How do you do that?

Comment: @migdesigns Can you tell whats the output of `date_default_timezone_get()` ?

Comment: @kantu it says America/Los Angeles

Answer (score 2):

Date/times are generally stored in the database as UTC, so if your timezone is UTC -7 hours then all your times will be out by 7 hours (between the database and your expected output).

When you load a date from the database you then have to apply the desired timezone before displaying it or doing calculations on it or whatever.

For some examples you can see what the date module does with:
[date_formatter_process()](http://drupalapi.alphanodes.com/api/date/date.module/function/date_formatter_process/7) and
[date_tokens()](http://drupalapi.alphanodes.com/api/date/date.tokens.inc/function/date_tokens/7)

It creates a new `DateObject and then runs date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open($timezone));` on that date to set the timezone.

If you just want to use the site timezone (or user selected timezone) you can use [date_default_timezone()](http://drupalapi.alphanodes.com/api/date/date_api!date_api.module/function/date_default_timezone/7).

There is also the drupal core function [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7), which takes a timestamp, a date format, and a timezone and gives you the output date.
That would be the easiest option.

For example, you might do this:

```
$okdate = format_date($nttdate, 'medium', '', date_default_timezone());
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the time is being stored as a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch), meaning the value will always be GMT/UTC no matter what your servers timezone is set to.

A unix timestamp will always return the number of seconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601` or `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`

If you store a datetime set created in America/Los_Angeles time it will be stored with a 7 hour difference when properly converted and stored as a unix timestamp (always GMT/UTC).

I will update my answer if you will post the DB type and DB Field type that is being used to store the datetime data.